# How to find all the used IP addresses on a network

Tags: networking

In my work there is a lot of computer and I want make a joke. I can close computer over the network but finding IP addresses is hard to me.

How can I easily find all online IP adresses from 192.168.1.aa to 192.168.1.zz?

Comment: try `angry ip scanner`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find unused IP Address on a network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64548/how-to-find-unused-ip-address-on-a-network)

Comment: seriously? you want our help to prank your coworkers?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Generally, `nmap` is quite useful to quickly scan networks.

To install nmap, enter the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Once the application is installed, enter the following command:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

This will show you which hosts responded to ping requests on the network between 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.255.

---

For older versions of Nmap, use `-sP`:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

---

For additional references, see the following pages:

[NMAP Installation Guide](https://nmap.org/book/install.html)

[NMAP Reference Guide](https://nmap.org/book/man.html)

It is a very useful tool to learn.

Comment: Not all hosts respond to pings. ARP is the way to go, at least in IPv4.

Comment: thats enough for me and it works on internet

Comment: is it just my computer, or does this command take forever to run?

Comment: Note, to speed up nmap scan you should add -T4 (speed) and -n (numeric only) flags.

Comment: Remember that you need **sudo** for nmap command, otherwise zero results is returned.

Comment: What does the `/24` do after the IP Address?

Comment: is it possible to check the ip with a certain username? Like I want to check the IP addresses which only has my user account on it? is it possible

Answer (score 43):

If all the computers in your network are Ubuntu or any other distribution that makes use of `avahi-daemon` ([DNS-SD](http://www.dns-sd.org/)), you can get a detailed list of them (with hostname and IP address) by doing:

```
avahi-browse -rt _workstation._tcp
```

If you want to know all the IP addresses used in your network, you can use `arp-scan`:

```
sudo arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24
```

As it is not installed by default, you'll have to install it with `sudo apt-get install arp-scan`. `arp-scan` send ARP packets to the local network and displays the responses received, so it shows even firewalled hosts (that block traffic based on IP packets).

Comment: This command is definitely better than the one above. Running nmap took ages, but this one replied instantly with the nodes in the specified network.

Comment: In my case, very often, `arp-scan` doesn't find all the devices associated to my wireless network. Now, for example, `sudo arp-scan 192.168.2.0/24` shows 2 results (.1 and .1), while  `nmap -sn 192.168.2.0/24` shows 4 results (.1, .2, .3 and .4). So, it seems that `nmap` is more accurate (I know for sure that there is 4 devices attached to the network). Why is this?

Comment: Maybe I found the answer in a comment to another question. "It should be noted that some devices might not show up unless they are turned on. My nexus 4 won't show up unless the screen is on." However, it's interesting that the same devices always respond to pings from `nmap`.

Comment: `arp-scan` is nice !

Comment: what are the available options other than `_workstation._tcp`

Answer (score 20):

**Note to the reader**: Original answer has been posted a while ago and at the time of when I was only learning shell scripting. See the revisited version below for a new and improved script that performs much faster.

#### Original Answer

`nmap` would be my #1 choice, but what if you don't have it ? The DIY way would be with a ping script that goes through each possible ip address on the network manually. What we have here is just while loop, where we set last number in the address, make silent single ping to the address, check if the command succeed or not (and if it did succeed,then host is obviously up ), and `printf` statement. Quick and dirty way, took me about 10 mins to write it, but runtime might be a bit slow,though.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# set -x
NUM=1

while [ $NUM -lt 256  ];do 
    ping -q -c 1 192.168.0.$NUM > /dev/null 
    RESULT=$(echo $?)
    if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then 
        printf 192.168.0.$NUM"\n"
    fi
    NUM=$(expr $NUM + 1)
done
```

#### Revisited Answer

I originally posted this answer in August of 2015. Since then I've learned  a bit more about shell scripting, and I once I saw this script, I thought it would be a good idea to revisit this answer to add a few improvements. Here's a few ideas:

- The script is obviously slow and `ping` waits for response from the host. By default, `ping` for two RTT, which can vary depending on how congested is your network , and as far as I understand TCP protocol doubles the wait time each time(at least according to [this](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2014/04/29/understanding-rtt-impact-on-tcp-retransmissions/)). So we could force `ping` to time out with `-w 1` flag.  Since we have 256 addresses and we assume 1 second for each address, the script will take about 256/60 = 4.27 minutes.
- Doing a command and then capturing its exit status with `$?` wasn't really necessary. The `if ... then;...fi` can operate on commands directly. In other words, it's sufficient to do this:

  ```
  if ping -w 1 -q -c 1 192.168.0.$NUM > /dev/null ;
  then
       <some other code here>
  fi
  ```
- The `printf` command can be rewritten as so:

  ```
  printf "IP %s is up\n" 192.168.0."$NUM"
  ```

  This is more of a stylistic change, but it's consistent with how `printf` works and looks like in a lot of other languages, with quoting `"$NUM"` variable. Quoting here isn't necessary - since we're dealing with numbers only, we don't need to anticipate word-splitting due to having spaces in a variable.
- Much better performance improvement can be achieved if we spawn several background processes.  The script edit below does exactly that. I put the `ping` and  `printf` into a function, `pingf` (yes, corny name, I know). Now, there's also one single `main` function which does the looping and calling of `pingf`.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment for debugging
#set -x
pingf(){
    if ping -w 2 -q -c 1 192.168.0."$1" > /dev/null ;
    then 
        printf "IP %s is up\n" 192.168.0."$1"
    fi
}

main(){

    NUM=1
    while [ $NUM -lt 255  ];do 
        pingf "$NUM" &
        NUM=$(expr "$NUM" + 1)
    done
    wait
}

main
```

How much better does that work ? Not bad, actually, takes a matter of seconds.

```
$ time ./ping_script.sh                                                                      
IP 192.168.0.1 is up
IP 192.168.0.101 is up
IP 192.168.0.27 is up
IP 192.168.0.29 is up
    0m02.50s real     0m00.01s user     0m00.12s system
```

#### Things to Keep in Mind

- Windows ( starting since Windows 7 , I think ) have started blocking response to ICMP echo requests. There's quite a few questions about that on Ask Ubuntu and other sites of the sort "Hey, my Linux computer can be pinged, but not Windows ones, what's up with that ?" Just be aware of the fact that for newer Windows versions you do need to enable response to ICMP echo.

Comment: I like this kind of solution

Comment: Me too. Very quickly scans the entire range with ping and no other software. Nice!

Answer (score 16):

Netdiscover can be your answer.

To install via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install netdiscover
```

example usage :

```
sudo netdiscover -r 192.168.1.0/24 -i wlan0
```

An IP with MAC Addreses will show on your terminal. See the screenshot

[image]

hope help you

[reference](http://www.linuxslaves.com/2015/08/how-to-use-netdiscover-to-find-ip-and-mac-addres.html)

Comment: Seems very buggy, first try [and `*** buffer overflow detected ***: netdiscover terminated`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netdiscover/+bug/291005).

Comment: This tool doesn't find several things on my network.

Answer (score 4):

`fping` is a great tool to scan multiple hosts on a network via ICMP. If not installed, you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install fping
```

`fping` sends ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets and mark a host as Up if it gets ECHO_RESPONSE from the host.

For example, to scan the hosts of subnet `192.168.1.0/24`, you can do:

```
fping -g 192.168.1.0/24
```

For a specific number of hosts e.g. from `192.168.1.15` to `192.168.1.140`:

```
fping -g 192.168.1.15 192.168.1.140
```

`fping` is highly configurable e.g. how many packets will be sent, the time to wait for response, output format etc.

Check `man fping` to get more idea.