# How to find all the used IP addresses by Ubuntu systems on a network?

Tags: 12.04, networking

What command can I use to get a list of IP addresses used by Ubuntu systems in LAN network?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/224620/65926

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all the used IP addresses on a network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224559/how-to-find-all-the-used-ip-addresses-on-a-network)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nmap` to get a list of ip's that are up:

```
nmap -sP 10.10.10.0/24
```

To find out if they are Ubuntu systems is harder. You can use a portscan (`-sS, -sT or -sF` for instance) and the `-O` option.

This does require you to have admin privileges, so you'd do something like

```
sudo nmap -sT -O  10.10.10.0/24
```

For ranges (the 0/24 part) and the options, you can check out the manpage of `nmap`.

Comment: only for linux and ubuntu systems.

Comment: I don't think that asking how to find servers on another OS would be ontopic?

Answer (score 0):

Try `nmap -sP -A 192.168.1.1/24`.