# How to check Active Linux machines in LAN

Tags: networking

How to check Active Linux machines in LAN.In ubuntu 12.04.
Anyone knows please suggest me.

Comment: i want with OS info filter only LINUX machines....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all the used IP addresses on a network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224559/how-to-find-all-the-used-ip-addresses-on-a-network)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `Zenmap`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install zenmap
   ```

Zenmap contains the possibility to filter by operating system.

2. You can also use `nmap`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nmap
   sudo nmap -O --osscan-limit --max-os-tries 1 <your_ip_range>
   ```

using `nmap` you have to look for Linux.

Comment: does it will give only linux machines,nmap -O --osscan-limit --max-os-tries 1 <your_ip_range>

Comment: That's what I already wrote in my reply. `... There is the possibility to filter by operating system. ...` and `... There you have still looking for Linux. ...`

Comment: @khanthegeek Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)